# Traceback (most recent call last) f1 = open(files, 'r') TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python

Iam writing code for editing many files in the working directory and when I run it brings the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hilary.kansiime\Documents\SHARE FOLDER\1-2JUN\test2.py", line 4
, in <module>
    f1 = open(files, 'r')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

below is the code I wrote

```
    import os
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    f1 = open(files, 'r')
    f2 = open(files+'.tmp', 'w')

    for line in f1:
        f2.write(line.replace('<Placemark xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">', '<Placemark xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2"><car>'+files+'</car>'))


    f1.close()
    f2.close()
```

I need your help

Answer (score 0):

`files` is a `list`. Instead of

```
f1 = open(files, 'r')
f2 = open(files+'.tmp', 'w')
```

you need

```
f1 = open(f, 'r')
f2 = open(f+'.tmp', 'w')
```

or just

```
for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as f1, open(f+'.tmp', 'w') as f2:
        for line in f1:
            f2.write(line.replace('<Placemark xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">', '<Placemark xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2"><car>'+files+'</car>'))
```